# working for MySQL connect in java. Why am I getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error?

Tags: java, mysql

```
sorry im first
```

> **library** mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar, jsoup-1.13.1.jar

> import

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class SQLLostProperty {
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://apis.data.go.kr/1320000/LosfundInfoInqireService/getLosfundInfoAccToClAreaPd"); /*URL*/
    urlBuilder.append("?" + URLEncoder.encode("serviceKey","UTF-8") + "=wLnaMueBw2fSWQSMJ0m9J5oPYpaQsysWiHAWpJ%2BkJcHu09yps%2FMksIuW07Sp%2FS4%2FebmwCJP55bL9kZebODnI%2Bg%3D%3D"); /*Service Key*/
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("PRDT_CL_CD_01","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("PRH000", "UTF-8"));
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("PRDT_CL_CD_02","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("PRH200", "UTF-8")); 
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("START_YMD","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("20120302", "UTF-8")); 
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("END_YMD","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("20211009", "UTF-8")); 
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("N_FD_LCT_CD","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("LCA000", "UTF-8"));
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("pageNo","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8")); /*페이지 번호*/
    urlBuilder.append("&" + URLEncoder.encode("numOfRows","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("99999", "UTF-8")); 
    URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.toString());        
    ArrayList<String> atcId = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> clrNm = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> depPlace = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> fdPrdtNm = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> fdSbjt = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> fdYmd = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> prdtClNm = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    ArrayList<String> rnum = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
 
    
    ArrayList<ArrayList> order = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    order.add(atcId);
    order.add(clrNm);
    order.add(depPlace);
    order.add(fdPrdtNm);
    order.add(fdSbjt);
    order.add(fdYmd);
    order.add(prdtClNm);
    order.add(rnum);
    
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
    str.add("item > atcId");
    str.add("item > clrNm");
    str.add("item > depPlace");
    str.add("item > fdPrdtNm");
    str.add("item > fdSbjt");
    str.add("item > fdYmd");
    str.add("item > prdtClNm");
    str.add("item > rnum");
    
    Iterator<String> iterator = str.iterator(); //Iterator for select
    Iterator<ArrayList> iterator1 = order.iterator(); // Iterator for ArrayList
   
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = null;   
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements ele = null;
        try {
            ele = doc.select(iterator.next()); 
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Iterator<Element> ie1 = ele.iterator();
        ArrayList array = iterator1.next(); // select Array
        while(ie1.hasNext()) {
            array.add(ie1.next().text());
        }
    }
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; // driver
    String sql = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stuff?useSSL=false"; //mysql url
    String user = "root"; 
    String pw = "rladydals2@";  
    String SQL = "insert into lost_property(atcId, clrNm, depPlace, fdPrdtNm, fdSbjt, fdYmd, prdtClNm, rnum) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    for(int i=0;i<atcId.size();i++) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(sql, user, pw);
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pstmt.setString(1, atcId.get(i));
            pstmt.setString(2, clrNm.get(i)); 
            pstmt.setString(3, depPlace.get(i)); 
            pstmt.setString(4, fdPrdtNm.get(i)); 
            pstmt.setString(5, fdSbjt.get(i));
            pstmt.setString(6, fdYmd.get(i));
            pstmt.setString(7, prdtClNm.get(i));
            pstmt.setString(8, rnum.get(i));
            int r = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("row : " + r);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("[SQL Error : " + e.getMessage() + "]");

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("[JDBC Connector Driver error : " + e1.getMessage() + "]");
        }finally {
            if (pstmt != null) {
                try {
                    pstmt.close();
                }catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                     con.close();
                }catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

}

```
> error
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2023 out of bounds for length 2023
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
at practice_1.SQLLostProperty.main(SQLLostProperty.java:101)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume at this point you want to access an array-field which is outside of the length of your array (outofboundexecption):

```
        ArrayList array = iterator1.next(); // select Array
    while(ie1.hasNext()) {
        array.add(ie1.next().text());
    }
```

maybe you check your logic here...